# ASP.NET page POST only access

Tags: asp.net, ajax, post, get

I was wondering if it is possible to restrict access to an ASPX page to http POST request method only? This restricted page will be used to render some complex content. I want to use it for ajax calls which will return that content into a div on another page. Is it possible to disable GET requests so that users won't be able to access it via URL in their browser by accident?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't prevent user from making a GET request. You can choose on server that you won't serve those. For example like:

```
  if (!string.Equals(Request.HttpMethod, "POST"))
  {
      Response.StatusCode = 405;
      Response.End();
  }
```

This can be implemented in `Page_Load` event or even in `HttpModule` (if you need it for more pages, etc).

Comment: Better to output a [405 status](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.6) than to throw an exception (which I assume will return a 500).

Comment: If you are using WebForms you could also use `Page.IsPostBack` instead of checking the `Request.HttpMethod`..

Comment: @TryingToImprove - that is common misconception - you can make PostBack even via GET request.

Comment: Did not know that you could do that. How?

Comment: @TryingToImprove - simply in your runat="server" form set method="get" and you'll see (IsPostBack will be true, but method will be get). This is not being used a lot for obvious reasons (there is only so many data get request can take), but it is a great way for hacker to forge request - so beware :)