# How to allow client to send data only by post method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net web form.I am giving my page's url(www.domainname.Test.aspx) to client.I want client should send data by post method only,how to do that?
Which is best content type for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32326741/2122217

on Page_Load

```
if (!string.Equals(Request.HttpMethod, "POST"))
{
   Response.StatusCode = 405;
   Response.End();
}
```